# arrange line in txt file in ASCII order using array and display them

Tags: c++, arrays, ascii

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    ifstream infile;          // ifstream is reading file
    infile.open("read.txt");  // read.txt is the file we need to read
    std::cout << infile;
    string str;
    if (infile.is_open()) {
        while (getline(infile, str)) {
            char str[2000], ch;
            int i, j, len;
            len = strlen(str);
            for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                for (j = 0; j < (len - 1); j++) {
                    if (str[j] > str[j + 1]) {
                        ch = str[j];
                        str[j] = str[j + 1];
                        str[j + 1] = ch;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        cout << "\nProcessed data:" << str;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

My txt file:

```
Today is a fine day.
It’s sunny.
Let us go out now!
```

My result should be:

```
    .Taaaddefiinosyy
 ’.Innsstuy
    !Legnooosttuuw
```

Spaces is consider here as well.
I'm new to C++.
I need some pros help.
Thank you very much!

Comment: *I m new to c++* -- Stop using `C`-string style functions, such as `strlen`, and raw character arrays.  Use `std::string` throughout the entire code.  Also, you did not include `<string>`.

Comment: `std::string`, `std::vector` `std::sort` and you're done.

Comment: And *if* you really need to rely on C-API then actually you should rather include ´cwhatever´ instead of `whatever.h` as far as the standard library is concerned (unless you are writing headers compatible to C, of course).

Comment: `char str[2000], ch; /*...*/ strlen(str);` is undefined behaviour for reading uninitialised memory, by the way... And the array hides the `std::string` object – which one do you intend to use???

Comment: Have you considered `std::swap(str[j], str[j + 1])` instead of doing that manually? Well, obsolete, of course, if you use `std::sort`...

Comment: error: 'sort' is not a member of 'std' i cant use it

Comment: Missing include. Just Google: [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) which told you: ***Defined in header <algorithm>*** near the top of the help page.

Comment: @NKXK26 `#include <algorithm>`, `#include <vector>`

Comment: I still get the same error. Can someone send me example code for the top part. I cannot understand the suggestions you guys gave, i need a summary for every mistakes and solutions if possible.

Comment: Please do not overwrite your original question with a new question, as that will invalidate all answers to your question. I have reverted your edit. Feel free to post a new question or to add information to your existing question (as long as it does not change the question in such a way that it invalidates existing answers), or to leave a comment to one of the answers if you have a question specific to one of the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not work, because:

1. The line `std::cout << infile;` is wrong. If you want to print the result of [`istream::operator bool()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool) in order to determine whether the file was successfully opened, then you should write `std::cout << infile.operator bool();` or `std::cout << static_cast<bool>(infile);` instead. However, it would probably be better to simply write `std::cout << infile.fail();` or `std::cout << !infile.fail();`.
2. The function [`std::strlen`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strlen) requires as a parameter a pointer to a valid string. Maybe you intended to write `str.length()`? In that case, you should delete the declaration `char str[2000]`, because it shadows the declaration `string str;`.
3. You should print the sorted result immediately after sorting it, before it gets overwritten by the next line. Currently you are only printing the content `str` a single time at the end of your program, so you are only printing the last line.

After performing the fixes mentioned above, your code should look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    ifstream infile;          // ifstream is reading file
    infile.open("read.txt");  // read.txt is the file we need to read
    std::cout << infile.fail();
    string str;
    if (infile.is_open()) {
        while (getline(infile, str)) {
            char ch;
            int i, j, len;
            len = str.length();
            for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                for (j = 0; j < (len - 1); j++) {
                    if (str[j] > str[j + 1]) {
                        ch = str[j];
                        str[j] = str[j + 1];
                        str[j + 1] = ch;
                    }
                }
            }

            cout << "\nProcessed data:" << str;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

For the input

```
Today is a fine day.
It's sunny.
Let us go out now!
```

this program has the following output:

```
0
Processed data:    .Taaaddefiinosyy
Processed data: '.Innsstuy
Processed data:    !Legnooosttuuw
```

Note that the input posted in your question contains a forward tick `’` instead of an apostrophe `'`. This could cause trouble. For example, when I tested your program, this forward tick was encoded into a multi-byte UTF-8 character, because it is not representable in 7-bit [US-ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII). This caused your sorting algorithm to fail, because it only supports single-byte characters. I was only able to fix this bug by replacing the forward tick with an apostrophe in the input.

Comment: can i ask why the last part, for ( auto &line : lines ) gives the warning  range-based 'for' loops only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11

Comment: the "lines" like no colour

Comment: @NKXK26: [Range-based `for` loops](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) were added to ISO C++11, i.e. they were added 11 years ago to the language. Is this a school project in which you are restricted to using a very old version of the language? If you want to compile with the latest version of the language, I recommend that you compile with the `-std=c++20` command-line option.

Comment: yes is school project,

Comment: i shouldnt use the array?

Comment: @NKXK26: Using `std::string` and `std::vector` is a lot easier to use, so I don't recommend using a C-style array, unless you are required to by the school project.

Comment: yes i have to use array

Comment: i only can understand the reading file part the rest i dont understand

Comment: @NKXK26: I assume that means that you are not allowed to use `std::vector` and `std::sort`. Are you allowed to use `std::string`? Or are you required to use C-style strings, i.e. arrays of `char` instead?

Comment: I can use string school never teach sort and vector

Comment: I need code using array to solve this i m so confuse ,I stuck here 1 week and deadline almost come

Comment: @NKXK26: Instead of using a `std::vector`, you could use a fixed-length array of `std::string`, i.e. `std::string lines[100];`. This should allow you to store up to 100 lines from the text file. You could then sort this array.

Comment: @NKXK26: I have now added another solution to my answer, uses a fixed-length array of `std::string` instead of `std::vector`. It also does not use `std::sort`.

Comment: There's absolutely no need for neither vector nor array – just read in a single line, sort it (custom sort or `std::sort` doesn't matter here) and print the line immediately...

Comment: @Aconcagua: Yes, you are correct. I thought that OP wanted to sort the lines with respect to other lines, instead of sorting all characters on each line. I have therefore discarded my answer and rewritten it.

Comment: @NKXK26: It appears that I misunderstood your question at first. See my previous comment for further information. Please take a look at my answer now, which I have rewritten. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 2):

Making use of the STL:

- Read your file line by line into a `std::string` using `std::getline`.
- Sort every line using `std::ranges::sort`.
- Print it.

The example below:

- also uses the `fmt` library instead of `std::cout`, and
- reads from a `std::istringstream` instead of a `std::ifstream`.

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/s859nExrE)

```cpp
#include <algorithm>  // sort
#include <fmt/core.h>
#include <sstream>  // istringstream
#include <string>  // getline

int main() {
    std::istringstream iss{
        "Today is a fine day.\n"
        "It's sunny.\n"
        "Let us go out now!\n"
    };

    fmt::print("Original file:\n{}\n", iss.str());

    fmt::print("Processed file:\n");
    std::string line{};
    while (std::getline(iss, line)) {
        std::ranges::sort(line);
        fmt::print("{}\n", line);
    }
}


// Outputs:
//
//   Original file:
//   Today is a fine day.
//   It's sunny.
//   Let us go out now!
//   
//   Processed file:
//       .Taaaddefiinosyy
//    '.Innsstuy
//       !Legnooosttuuw
```

Comment: There's absolutely no need for the vector – just read one line, sort it and print it immediately afterwards...

Comment: Ah yes, thanks for noticing! I'll update my answer. In my initial response I was sorting the file lines; that's why I was using the vector. Then I understood the OP just wanted to sort each line and I changed my answer, but I kept the vector.